# stored procedure succeeds on one machine but fails on another?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Strange problem. When I create a stored procedure on one SQL server it succeeds but exactly the same code fails on another. They succeed both when the line 'select s from dbo.Split' is removed

The errors are

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DeliveryReportFFF, Line 38
>   Incorrect syntax near 'd2'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DeliveryReportFFF, Line 65
>   Incorrect syntax near '+'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DeliveryReportFFF, Line 75
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DeliveryReportFFF, Line 81
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DeliveryReportFFF, Line 87
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DeliveryReportFFF, Line 93
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
>   Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DeliveryReportFFF, Line 101
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

The first error complains about the d2.DeliveryLocation as the argument to Split.

The SSMS version is 2012. What could be wrong here?

```
SELECT 
   row_number() over (order by o.OrderNumber, d2.DeliveryNumber, pd.TariffType) as Row 
   , d.BookTime
   , d2.DeliveryRoute
   , (select s from dbo.Split(' ', d2.DeliveryLocation) where pn = 2) as SorterExit
   , d2.DeliveryLocation
FROM Delivery d WITH (NOLOCK)
```

The split UDF looks like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (@sep nchar(1), @s nvarchar(512))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (
    WITH tokens(pn, start, stop) AS (
      SELECT 1, 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT pn + 1, stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @s, stop + 1)
      FROM tokens
      WHERE stop > 0
    )
    SELECT pn,
      SUBSTRING(@s, start, CASE WHEN stop > 0 THEN stop-start ELSE 512 END) AS s
    FROM tokens
  )
```

Comment: Fails how? What error message?

Comment: Do you have `Split` function on both servers?

Comment: Are the functions Split identical on both servers, do you have permissions to Split on both servers ? My guess is you are missing the permissions. Easy test to try permisssions: select * from [dbo].[Split] (' ', null)

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Pointless guessing when the OP could just **tell us** the error message.

Comment: ok, edited in the error messages

Comment: The version of SSMS is irrelevant. What is `@@VERSION` on both servers? Is one less than or equal to 2000? And compatibility level of databases if not?

Comment: ah! one server is Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2218.0 (X64) 
and the other is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using it as an outer apply.

```
SELECT row_number() over (order by o.OrderNumber, d2.DeliveryNumber, pd.TariffType) as Row 
, d.BookTime
, d2.DeliveryRoute
, s.s as SorterExit
, d2.DeliveryLocation
FROM Delivery d WITH (NOLOCK)
OUTER APPLY dbo.Split(' ', d2.DeliveryLocation) as s
```